# GAS How to get last column?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I want to know how to get last column from specific rows in spreadsheet.

```
function myFunction() {
 var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
 var sheet = ss.getSheets()[0];
 var range = sheet.getRange("A:A").getValues();
 var lastrow = range.filter(String).length;
```

This is the way get last row, and I want to know this version of last column.
Look at this. I want to know each row's last column. For example, A2's last column is "6".
[image]

If any, please tell me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about this sample script? In this sample, last column of each row is retrieved by counting the number of cells from the maximum column using `getLastColumn()`. The retrieved data is outputted as JSON.

### Sample script :

```
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
var data = ss.getDataRange().getValues();
var res = [];
var cols = ss.getLastColumn();
data.forEach(function(e, i){
  for (var j=cols-1; j>=0; j--) {
    if (e[j] != "") {
      res.push({row: i + 1, col: j + 1});
      break;
    }
  }
});
Logger.log(JSON.stringify(res))
```

### Sample sheet :

[image]

### Result :

```
[
    {"row":1,"col":1},
    {"row":2,"col":2},
    {"row":3,"col":3},
    {"row":4,"col":4},
    {"row":5,"col":5},
    {"row":6,"col":6},
    {"row":7,"col":7},
    {"row":8,"col":8},
    {"row":9,"col":9},
    {"row":10,"col":10}
]
```

Comment: @user6725119 Welcome. Thank you, too.

Answer (score 0):

```js
function getLastColumninaRow() {
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet()
  // select the first non blank cell and activate  that we want 
  // to get the Last Column that is non Blank 
  spreadsheet.getRange('H7').activate();
  // the following line will select the whole line until blank the last cell;
  spreadsheet.getSelection()
    .getNextDataRange(SpreadsheetApp.Direction.NEXT).activate();
  var Rng = spreadsheet.getActiveRange().getA1Notation()
  Logger.log('Rng %s', Rng)
  // Youll get the last Range in a Row in A1 Notation
};
```