# How to loop through all columns in spreadsheet?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a function that change the background color of cells.
Function works well and do the thing I want, but I met one problem that I don't really know how to solve.

I want this function to loop through all used columns in spreadsheet. (for now it is from G till TP column will increase)

As you can see the function I have now do the thing only with G column.
How to make it loop till the last used column?

```
    function insertColor2() {
  const sheetName = "結果１";  // set the sheet name.

  // 1. Retrieve values from sheet.
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  const sheet = ss.getSheetByName(sheetName);
  const values1 = sheet.getRange(3, 7, sheet.getLastRow() - 2,1).getValues();
  const values = [];
  values.push(values1);
  

  // 2. Create an array for modifying the background colors.
  const backgroundColors = values.map(([,,c,,,...g]) =>
    g.reduce((o, e) => {
      if (e.toString() != "") {
        o.total += e;
        o.colors.push(c >= o.total ? null : "red");
      } else {
        o.colors.push(null);
      }
      return o;
    }, {colors: [], total: 0}).colors
  );
  
  const flatten = [].concat.apply([], backgroundColors);
  const newArr = [];
  while(flatten.length) newArr.push(flatten.splice(0,1));
  Logger.log(newArr);

  // 3. Modify the background colors of cells.
  sheet.getRange(8, 7, newArr.length, 1).setBackgrounds(newArr);
}
```

Comment: If your problem is to find the last column, then [you have this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46705260/gas-how-to-get-last-column) and also [this documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getlastcolumn)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [GAS How to get last column?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46705260/gas-how-to-get-last-column)

Comment: I know how to find the last column, I just have no idea how can I loop this function. `const values1 = sheet.getRange(3, 7, sheet.getLastRow() - 2,1).getValues();` here 7 should change everytime at first 7 then 8, 9, 10. I think that would be correct logic but it might also take a time to loop 300 columns

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I found a solution to solve this problem. It is not the best solution but works well. I just simply transposed array twice at the beginning and before inputting result to the sheet.

```
    function transpose(a) {
    return Object.keys(a[0]).map(function(c) {
        return a.map(function(r) { return r[c]; });
    });
}

function transpose1(original) {
    var copy = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < original.length; ++i) {
        for (var j = 0; j < original[i].length; ++j) {
            // skip undefined values to preserve sparse array
            if (original[i][j] === undefined) continue;
            // create row if it doesn't exist yet
            if (copy[j] === undefined) copy[j] = [];
            // swap the x and y coords for the copy
            copy[j][i] = original[i][j];
        }
    }
    return copy;
}

function insertColor5() {
  const sheetName = "結果１";  // Please set the sheet name.

  // 1. Retrieve values from sheet.
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  const sheet = ss.getSheetByName(sheetName);
  const values1 = sheet.getRange(3, 7, sheet.getLastRow() - 2, sheet.getLastColumn()).getValues();

  const values = transpose(values1);
  
  //Logger.log(values);

  // 2. Create an array for modifying the background colors.
  const backgroundColors = values.map(([,,c,,,...g]) =>
    g.reduce((o, e) => {
      if (e.toString() != "") {
        o.total += e;
        o.colors.push(c >= o.total ? null : "red");
      } else {
        o.colors.push(null);
      }
      return o;
    }, {colors: [], total: 0}).colors
  );

const kolorki = transpose1(backgroundColors);
  //Logger.log(transpose1(backgroundColors));
  
  // 3. Modify the background colors of cells.
  sheet.getRange(8, 7, kolorki.length, kolorki[0].length).setBackgrounds(kolorki);
}
```